# Zero As Primary Key In SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to insert `0` in the primary key field of a table in SQL server 2008?

Comment: Numerical ZERO - yes. NULL - no. A primary key **must** be NOT NULL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long it's a numeric field, yes... follow along at home!

```
create table TestTable
(
    TestColumn int not null primary key
)

insert TestTable values(0)
```

The `primary key` restriction only requires that the value be unique and the column not be nullable.

For an `identity` field:

```
create table TestTable
(
    TestColumn int identity(1, 1) not null primary key --start at 1
)

set identity_insert TestTable on
insert TestTable (TestColumn) values (0) --explicitly insert 0
set identity_insert TestTable off
```

The `identity(1, 1)` means "start at one and increment by one each time something is inserted". You could have `identity(-100, 10)` to start at `-100` and increment by `10` each time. Or you could start at `0`. There's no restriction.

You can generally answer questions like these for yourself by just trying them and seeing if they work. This is faster and usually more beneficial than asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: is it possible in identity field...? is it possible to start identity from ZERO?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be zero. The value can be from −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, from −(2^31) to 2^31 − 1, the full range of an unsigned integer.

If you expect a lot of records, like up to 4.3 billion, it makes sense to start from the smallest value, and work your way up.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    TestColumn INT IDENTITY(−2,147,483,648, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY --start at 1
)
```